# Getting an MBean property in a JSP

Tags: jsp, properties, javabeans, jmx

I'm trying to access an MBean property managed through JMX directly in a JSP page. 
I've tried using something like this

```
<jsp:useBean id="beanName" class="com.example.MBeanClass" scope="application" />
```

This gave no error, but once I tried `<%= beanName.getPropert() %>`, null was printed. I went to the JMX manager page and verified that bean was initialized and had all the properties correctly set, so my theory is that my code is somehow creating a new instance of the bean instead of utilizing the existing one.

According to the useBean documentation I read, anything between the jsp:useBean tag is run whenever a new bean is created only. So I modified my code to be something like this:

```
<jsp:useBean id="beanName" class="com.example.MBeanClass" scope="application" />
    <jsp:setProperty name="beanName" property="propertyName" value="12345" />
</jsp:useBean>
```

Which still resulted in `null` being printed. So my view *wasn't* creating a new bean after all. So why is it returning null when JMX clearly shows the value is set?

I feel like I need a deeper understanding of what's going on in order to debug this, as I'm at a point where I'm resorting to randomly changing code around to see if something magically works. I've also played around with the scope attribute from useBean and with other attributes with no success.

Answer (score 1):

JMX beans are magically visible to JSP pages. JMX is a separate API (`javax.management`) and manages its beans internally, and there generally little reason to try to join the two together.

If you need to access a JMX bean in your JSP page, then you need to either embed a Java scriptlet in your JSP that calls the `javax.management` API (see [this rather unpleasant example here](http://java-monitor.com/forum/showthread.php?t=618), or have your servlet fetch the JMX bean via that same API, and then stick the JMX bean as a request attribute. Your JSP can then fetch the bean as it would any other.

(If you don't have a servlet acting as controller for your JSP, then you really should do).